# Panel data in Keras LSTM

Tags: neural-network, keras, lstm, panel-data

I am looking at panel data, which is structured like this:

`D = \{(x^{(k)}_{t},y^{(k)}_{t})\,|\, k=1,\dots,N\, , t=t_0,\dots,t_k \}_{k=1}^{N}`

where  `x^{(k)}`  denotes the  `k`'th sequence,  `x^{(k)}_{t}`  denotes the  `k`'th sequences value at time  `t` , furthermore  `x^{(k)}_{i,t}`  is the `i`'th entry in the vector `x^{(k)}_{t}`. That is `x^{(k)}_{t}` is the feature vector of the `k`'th sequence at time `t`. The sub- and super scripts mean the same things for the label data `y^{(k)}_{t}`, but here `y^{(k)}_{t} \in \{0,1\}`.

In plain words: The data set contains individuals observed over time, and for each time point at which an individual is observed, it is recorded whether he bought an item or not ( `y\in \{0,1\}`).

I would like to use a recurrent neural network with LSTM units from Keras for the task of predicting whether a person will buy an item or not, at a given time point. I have only been able to find examples of RNN's where each sequence has a label value ([philipperemy link](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/)), not an example where each sequence element has a label value as in the problem I described.

My approach so far, has been to create a tensor with dimensions (samples,timesteps,features) but I cannot figure out how to format the labels, such that `keras` can match them with the features. It should be something like this (samples,timesteps,1), where the last dimension indicates a single dimension to contain the label value of 0 or 1.

Furthermore some of the approaches that I have come across splits sequences such that subsequences are add to the training data, thus increasing the need for memory tremendously ([mlmastery link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)). This is infeasible in my case, as I have multiple GB's of data, and I would not be able to store it in memory if I added subsequences.

The model I would like to use is something like this:

```
mod = Sequential()
mod.add(LSTM(30,input_dim=116, return_sequences = True))
mod.add(LSTM(10))
mod.add(Dense(2))
```

Does anyone have experience working with panel data in `keras`?

Comment: Math mode doesnt seem work, I followed this tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I am wondering if you are still on stackoverflow and if you would mind posting your data and full model? I am trying to learn keras for panel and my data is similar to yours, but there is not much out there for panel keras examples.

Comment: Hi John, unfortunately I don't have access to the data or the model anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
mod = Sequential()
mod.add(LSTM(30, input_shape=(timesteps, features), return_sequences = True))
mod.add(LSTM(10, return_sequences = True))
mod.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
# In newest Keras version you can change the line above to mod.add(Dense(1, ..))

mod.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

Comment: Does it matter what batch size you use for panel data? Can the batch size be more than 1 individual?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only option is to run the lstm for each individual (here it is a sequence) separately when the data is not balanced as I assume this since time depends on k in your question.